# Issue with HIVE with row_number() over() syntax

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive

I have HIVE table ( details below):

```
hive> select * from abcd ;
OK
a   1   1
b   2   2
a   3   3
Time taken: 0.261 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive> desc abcd;
OK
val001                  string                                      
val002                  int                                         
val003                  int                                         
Time taken: 0.084 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

I am writing following query but receiving below error :

```
select max(rnk) rnk, max(val) val, sum(cnt) cnt from (select val, count(*) cnt, row_number() over (order by case val  when null then 0 else count(*) end desc, val) rnk from (select VAL001 val from abcd ) group by val) group by case when rnk <= 100 or val is null then rnk else 100 + 1 end;

FAILED: ParseException line 3:55 missing ) at 'by' near 'by'
line 3:58 missing EOF at 'val' near 'by'
```

I am looking for following result from above query :

```
RNK VAL                CNT
--- ------------------------------ ---
1   a                    2
2   b                    1
```

I was able to achieve the same from Oracle database having similar kind of table. Only difference was instead of order by case I used order by decode in Oracle DB but since decode is not supported in HIVe I can not do the same.

Please find ORacle DB SQL query which is working :

```
    SQL> select max(rnk) rnk, max(val) val, sum(cnt) cnt from 
    (select val, count(*) cnt, row_number() over (order by 
    decode(val,null,0,count(*)) desc, val) rnk from (select VAL001 val from 
    table_name ) group by val)
    group by case when rnk <= 100 or val is null then rnk else 100 + 1 end;   

RNK VAL                CNT
--- ------------------------------ ---
 1 a                     2
 2 b                     1
```

Can anyone please help me fixing HIVE query. Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query.  I suspect there is a simpler way to get what you want:

```
select max(rnk) as rnk, max(val) as val, sum(cnt) as cnt
from (select val, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by case val when null then 0 else count(*) end desc, val) as rnk
      from (select VAL001 val from abcd )
      group by val
     )
group by case when rnk <= 100 or val is null then rnk else 100 + 1 end;
```

I think you just need table aliases for the subqueries in the `from` clause:

```
select max(rnk) as rnk, max(val) as val, sum(cnt) as cnt
from (select val, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by case val when null then 0 else count(*) end desc, val) as rnk
      from (select VAL001 val from abcd
           ) x
      group by val
     ) x
group by case when rnk <= 100 or val is null then rnk else 100 + 1 end;
```

Comment: This helped.. thanks a lot :)... Do you have suggestion for simpler version of this query as well.

Comment: You mean a single pass query to achive the result? This will bring an extra credit:)

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically simpler solution, but possible easier to read:

The first subquery performs the count and ranking,

the second subquery the categorisation in the `top 1 - top 100` and the special categories for `other (top)` and `unknown`.

The final query makes the grouping.

```
with cnt as (
 select VAL001 val, 
  count(*)  as cnt, 
  row_number() over (order by decode(VAL001,null,0,count(*)) desc, VAL001) as rnk
 from  abcd
 group by VAL001),
ctg as (
 select 
  val, cnt, rnk,
  case when val is NULL then 'unknown'
       when rnk <= 100 then 'top '||rnk
       else 'other' end as category_code
 from cnt)
select 
  max(rnk) as rnk, max(val) as val, sum(cnt) as cnt
from  ctg
group by category_code
order by 1
```